# build function to loop over dictionary of dictionaries to compute something from every nested dictionary individually

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, for-loop

very new to python and programming in general so bear with me. So the basic function loops over a simple dictionary, checks the values and if one of them is 0 it replaces that value with the mean of the rest of the group. This works!

```
def replace_zero(group):
for k, v in group.iteritems():
    if v == '-':
        print 'there was a - value!'
        group[k] = 0
        new_mean = sum(group.itervalues()) / (len(group.keys())-1)
        group[k] = new_mean
        return group[k]
    elif v == 0:
        print 'there was a zero value!'
        group[k] = 0
        new_mean = sum(group.itervalues()) / (len(group.keys())-1)
        group[k] = new_mean
        return group[k]
```

But due to my huge dataset i don't want to call this function 36 times, so i made 12 dictionaries, which contain 3 dictionaries each.

```
gr_ctr_0 = {'distance': {'A1': sheet['E5'].value, 'A12': sheet['E16'].value,
                     'B1': sheet['E17'].value, 'B12': sheet['E28'].value,
                     'C1': sheet['E29'].value, 'C12': sheet['E40'].value,
                     'D1': sheet['E41'].value, 'D12': sheet['E52'].value},
        'speed': {'A1': sheet['F5'].value, 'A12': sheet['F16'].value,
                  'B1': sheet['F17'].value, 'B12': sheet['F28'].value,
                  'C1': sheet['F29'].value, 'C12': sheet['F40'].value,
                  'D1': sheet['F41'].value, 'D12': sheet['F52'].value},
        'time': {'A1': sheet['G5'].value, 'A12': sheet['G16'].value,
                 'B1': sheet['G17'].value, 'B12': sheet['G28'].value,
                 'C1': sheet['G29'].value, 'C12': sheet['G40'].value,
                 'D1': sheet['G41'].value, 'D12': sheet['G52'].value}}
```

I would now like to extend my function so that i pass it one dictionary (gr_ctr_0), and it still replaces any 0 value with the mean of the nested dictionary (e.g inside 'distance')

I've read all the related questions and thought it would a relatively simple line where I just add something along the lines of

```
def replace_zero(main_dict):
    for group in main_dict:
        for k, v in group.iteritems():
```

but it doesn't work, like at all :( Alternatively I read something about the recursive function, however I would have no idea how to implement that! Thank you all in advance!

EDIT !!!

taking both comments into account, I came up with this solution

```
def replace_zero_stackoverflow(group):
    average = float(sum(group.itervalues())) / (len(group)- sum(v==0 for v in group.itervalues()))
    for k, v in group.iteritems():
        if v == 0:
            group[k] = average
    return group
res = {name: replace_zero_stackoverflow(group) for name, group in gr_ctr_0.iteritems()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your function:

```
def replace_zero(group):
    for k, v in group.iteritems():
        if v == '-' or v == 0:
            group[k] =  float(sum(group.itervalues())) / (len(group.keys())-1)
    return group
```

and this should work:

```
res = {name: replace_zero(group) for name, group in gr_ctr_0.items()}
```

You can apply your function to each group in your dictionary `gr_ctr_0`and create a result dictionary `res`.

Test:

```
gr_ctr_0 = {'distance': {'A1': 4, 'A12':0, 'A13':7},
            'speed': {'A1': 0, 'A12': 45, 'A13': 5.7},
            'time': {'A1': 3, 'A12': 40, 'A13': 20}}
res = {name: replace_zero(group) for name, group in gr_ctr_0.items()}
print(res)
```

Output:

```
{'distance': {'A1': 4, 'A13': 7, 'A12': 5.5}, 
 'speed': {'A1': 25.35, 'A13': 5.7, 'A12': 45},
 'time': {'A1': 3, 'A13': 20, 'A12': 40}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! First function works beautifully, except for the res part I had to add an extra
    elif v != 'v' or v != 0:
                return group

statement, because otherwise the sub-dictionaries where no 0 was found would have returned as none.

Answer (score 0):

Your function stop the first time that a match is found because it have a `return`, so it wouldn't check every sub dictionary if one of them have have a match, likewise it wouldn't check every value and also would fail if multiples `"-"` are inside or a combination of `"-"` and `0` (or any other combination of numbers and string for that matter)

For example

```
gr_ctr_0 = {'distance': { 'A1': 1, 'A12': 1, 'B1': '-', 'B12': 5,
                          'C1': 5, 'C12': 4, 'D1': 6,   'D12': '-'},
            'speed': { 'A1': 0, 'A12': 6, 'B1': 4, 'B12': 4,
                       'C1': 1, 'C12': 6, 'D1': 6, 'D12': 1},
            'time': { 'A1': 5, 'A12': 2, 'B1': 2, 'B12': 4,
                      'C1': 0, 'C12': 3, 'D1': 2, 'D12': '-'}
            }
```

with you original function it result in

```
>>> replace_zero(gr_ctr_0["distance"])
there was a - value!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    replace_zero(gr_ctr_0["distance"])
  File "C:\Users\David\Documents\Python Scripts\stackoverflow_test.py", line 53, in replace_zero
    new_mean = sum(group.itervalues()) / (len(group.keys())-1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
>>>
```

You first need to replace all the `"-"` (or all string) with a numbers and then you can replace a zero or all zero according to your desire.

To accomplished this, we can create another function that do the first step like

```
def clean_data(data, default=0):
    for k,v in data.iteritems():
        if v=="-": #isinstance(v,str):
            data[k] = default
    return data
```

the commented part is for the detection of any string, if necessary use that instead.

Now the `replace_zero` can call the clean function to ensure success like this

```
def replace_zero(group):
    group = clean_data(group)
    for k, v in group.iteritems():
        if v == 0:
            print 'there was a zero value!'
            group[k] = sum(group.itervalues()) / (len(group)-1)
            break
    return group
```

this function would only replace the first zero that it found, to replace all of them remove the break, also notice that in that case if there are multiples zeroes each one would have a different values, but if you want to replace all with the same value, you need to calculate that one first like this

```
def replace_zero(group):
    group = clean_data(group)
    average = sum(group.itervalues()) / (len(group)-1)
    for k, v in group.iteritems():
        if v == 0:
            print 'there was a zero value!'
            group[k] = average 
    return group
```

and in this case, if you want to ignore the zeroes for the average, you can change the `(len(group)-1)` for `( len(group)- sum( v==0 for v in group.itervalues() )` this `sum` would count how many 0 there are.

And finally, you can do as **Mike Müller** show you to get the final result or also like this

```
def replace_zero_in_groups(data):
    for k,v in data.iteritems():
        data[k] = replace_zero(v)
    return data
```

testing it with the example above (the replace all zeroes with the same average variant)

```
>>> replace_zero_in_groups(gr_ctr_0)
{'distance': {'A1': 1,
              'A12': 1,
              'B1': 3.6666666666666665,
              'B12': 5,
              'C1': 5,
              'C12': 4,
              'D1': 6,
              'D12': 3.6666666666666665},
 'speed': {'A1': 4.0,
           'A12': 6,
           'B1': 4,
           'B12': 4,
           'C1': 1,
           'C12': 6,
           'D1': 6,
           'D12': 1},
 'time': {'A1': 5,
          'A12': 2,
          'B1': 2,
          'B12': 4,
          'C1': 3.0,
          'C12': 3,
          'D1': 2,
          'D12': 3.0}}
>>>
```

(also, to ensure a correct division, add `from __future__ import division` at the start of the code)

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your detailed answer! And thanks a million for pointing out the multiple 0s issue! Ended up with

    def replace_zero_stackoverflow(group):
        average = sum(group.itervalues()) / (len(group)- sum(v==0 for v in group.itervalues()))
        for k, v in group.iteritems():
            if v == 0:
                group[k] = average
        return group
res = {name: replace_zero_stackoverflow(group) for name, group in gr_ctr_0.iteritems()}

didn't end up needing the elif v != 0: return group anymore, do you have any idea why that would be?

Comment: is difficult to analyze code in the comments, put it in your question on in http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Sorry hadnt realised it would mess up the formatting!